# if checkbox checked enable his textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html

in this php code i have foreach loop create textarea with checkbox for each statement 
i wanna to enable textarea if his checkbox is checked
but they have same id

```
<?php
  foreach($Arows as $row){ 
  echo '<tr class="row">
          <th class="col-sm-12"><h4>'.$row['Type_A'].'</h4></th>
        </tr>';
  $stmt3 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM sous_analyse WHERE Id_A =".$row['Id_A']);
  $stmt3->execute();
  $SArows = $stmt3->fetchAll();//Analyse rows
  foreach($SArows as $Srow){ 
  echo '<tr class="row">
          <td class="col-sm-4">'.$Srow['Parameter'].'</td>
          <td class=" col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control col-xl-12 border-secondary" name="Fonctionnalite" placeholder="RESULTATS" required=""></td>
          <td class="col-sm-3 text-center">'.$Srow['Normal'].'</td>
        </tr>';
      }
      echo '<tr class="row">
              <th class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon form-check">
                    <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox-grey" id="inputUnchecked" name="inputUnchecked">
                      <label for="inputUnchecked"></label>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="textareaDefault" rows="3" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 60px;" disabled></textarea>
                </div>
              </th>
            </tr>';
  }
?>
```

i use this script but is working in first textarea

```
<script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputUnchecked").on('click', function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("#textareaDefault").prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $("#textareaDefault").prop('disabled',true);
    }
    alert("fdg");
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. All HTML Elements must have a Unique ID. You will want to adjust your PHP such that it provides a unique ID for each textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you will want to adjust your PHP. This is easily done with a counter (`$c`).

```
<?php
foreach($Arows as $row){
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<tr class="row">'."\r\n";
    $html .= '<th class="col-sm-12"><h4>'.$row['Type_A'].'</h4></th>'."\r\n";
    $html .= '</tr>'."\r\n";
    $stmt3 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM sous_analyse WHERE Id_A =".$row['Id_A']);
    $stmt3->execute();
    $SArows = $stmt3->fetchAll();
    $c = 1;
    foreach($SArows as $Srow){ 
        $html .= '<tr class="row">'."\r\n";
        $html .= '<td class="col-sm-4">'.$Srow['Parameter'].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td class=" col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control col-xl-12 border-secondary" name="Fonctionnalite" placeholder="RESULTATS" required=""></td>';
        $html .= '<td class="col-sm-3 text-center">'.$Srow['Normal'].'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html .= '<tr class="row">';
    $html .= '<th class="col-sm-12">';
    $html .= '<div class="input-group">';
    $html .= '<span class="input-group-addon form-check">';
    $html .= '<span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">';
    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox-grey" id="inputUnchecked-$c" name="inputUnchecked">';
    $html .= '<label for="inputUnchecked-$c"></label>';
    $html .= '</span></span>';
    $html .= '<textarea class="form-control" id="textareaDefault-$c" rows="3" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 60px;" disabled></textarea>';
    $html .= '</div></th></tr>';
    echo $html;
    $c++;
}
?>
```

Your JavaScript can then use the ID since it is unique or can simply be relative to nearby elements.

```
$(function() {
  $("[id^='inputUnchecked-']").on('click', function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parent().parent().find("[id^='textareaDefault-']").prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().find("[id^='textareaDefault-']").prop('disabled',true);
    }
    alert("fdg");
  })
});
```

Comment: how i can use script (enable/disabled) textarea
thanks